# Storing & interacting with user sensitive data in SQL interconnected with Xcode

Tags: ios, sql, xcode, security, mobile

I’m new in iOS development and I want to create an application that a user needs to login to do payments and other actions that involves sensitive information, thus I want to know the best practices for storing user login credentials on data base. I know that when you use “Stripe” to do payments no credit card data is stored on your data base or app. But I have a doubt in storing other sensitive data such as passwords, directions and other info. I’ve looked in the internet for the best practices of storing this kind of information and came to the conclusion that I need to apply the following:
• **Encrypting passwords in the Data Base**
• **Use Keychain**
• **Use HTTPS**

I’m I in the correct path? Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for something like '*salting password hashing*'

Regarding Stripe, it should be okay to store the *last4* digits of the credit card (but even this can be extracted from Stripe, using the customer-id or charge-id).